# multiple dll repositories / GACs in Mono

Tags: mono

My Linux distributions installs Mono and a bunch of related libraries into /usr
Unfortunately this version of Mono is slightly out-of-date and does not allow for the installation of F#. I thus have another Mono installation into /opt

I however would prefer not to have to recompile all the libraries (Gdk# etc.) installed into /usr so as to have another version in /opt, but instead would like the Mono in /opt to

1. compile with libraries from /usr, if not found in /opt
2. load libraries from /usr

Point 2. seems achievable using MONO_GAC_PREFIX. How do I achieve point 1?